# Attempting to code a c program to return a string length by dividing the code into two separate functions

Tags: c

I've been through several examples and videos and feel like there's a basic misconception on my part somewhere that I'm not seeing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    char String;
    char *sendString;
    char getString[100];
    int counter;

    *sendString = String;

    printf("\nPlease enter string:\n");
    fgets(getString, 100, stdin);

    int calcLength(counter);

    printf("los1111: %d", counter);

    return 0;
}

int calcLength()
{
    char *sendString[100];
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; *sendString[counter] != '\0'; counter++);

    printf("los: %d", counter);
    return counter;
}
```

there are a couple of test 'los' printf functions to see where the code is breaking but that unfortunately is bringing me up nothing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is coding your own string length function instead of using "strlen()" an academic exercise?  Assuming it is, then you should "prototype" your "calcLength" before its use (before main() ).  You also have an issue with your calcLength function... i.e. what specifically is its job, to determine the lenth of a null-terminated string... but how does it "get" that string???  Additionally, you "call" calcLength passing it "counter" as an argument, but in the actual calcLength function, you do not specify an argument.  Lastly, is "counter" what you really want to pass???  Just things to think about

Comment: After re-reading this I noticed I've left out a lot of information.  I'm attempting to code a program for class that will reference a second function that separately calculates the length of a string input in the 'main' function. I'm thinking that a pass by reference will be easiest but the proper formatting eludes me.

Comment: I'll show you a prototype and its invocation , maybe you can figure out the function:   Prototype:   int calcLength(char *);  invocation: counter = calcLength(getString);   Hope this puts you on track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your over complicating it slightly.

In this block of code:

```
char String;
char *sendString;
char getString[100];
int counter;

*sendString = String;
```

You don't need most of these `char` declarations, if you only want to calculate the length of the string from [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

This can simply be reduced to:

```
char getstring[100];
int myStrLen;
```

Where you only need to give a string buffer to `fgets`, and an integer declaration `myStrLen`, used to calculate the final string length.

Additionally, there are some problems with your `calcLength()` function. You need to pass a `char []` parameter to this function, so it knows what string it needs to calculate the length of. It really should be as simple as this:

```
int
calcLength(char sendstring[]) {
    int counter, len = 0;

    for (counter = 0; sendstring[counter] != '\0'; counter++) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

With all of these recommendations, your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 100

int calcLength(char sendstring[]);

int 
main(void) {
    char getstring[BUFFSIZE];
    int myStrLen;

    printf("\nPlease enter string:\n");
    if (fgets(getstring, BUFFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        getstring[strlen(getstring)-1] = '\0'; // To remove '\n' character from fgets()
    }

    myStrLen = calcLength(getstring);

    printf("String length = %d\n", myStrLen);

    return 0;
}

int
calcLength(char sendstring[]) {
    int counter, len = 0;

    // Every valid character found, increment a counter
    for (counter = 0; sendstring[counter] != '\0'; counter++) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Note: This code can be improved, but it should help point you in the right direction. I've added some comments in the code for clarification.

Comment: @Nicholas Brasher, I'm glad I could help :)